# Is there a quick key command that will switch frames in Flash?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, navigation, adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

I have Adobe Flash CS4 and was wondering if there was a quick keyboard command that would allow me to navigate to the next frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Action                    Key
========================  ===
Step Forward One Frame     .
Step Backward One Frame    ,
```

**Adobe Flash Cheatsheet**
http://www.customguide.com/pdf/flash-quick-reference-cs3.pdf (CS3)
http://subdivision.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/FlashCS4_PC_Shortcuts.pdf (CS4)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **comma** and the **period** to go backwards and forwards respectively. It helps to remember them as the brackets on keys themselves **<** and **>**, but don't actually hold shift when you press them.

**F5** makes a new blank KeyFrame

**F6** copies your current Frame onto the next one

**F7** makes a new blank KeyFrame

You can edit any of these in the Edit>Keyboard Shortcuts to suit your tastes as well.

Answer (score 0):

F5 for new frame, F6 for new keyframe (duplicate of current), F7 for new blank keyframe. Use the `,` and `.` keys to navigate left and right respectively in existing frames.